# Can't select User ID from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm trying to select user's subordinates from Salesforce, but a simple query

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ManagerId=xxxxxxxxx
```

returns bunch of null values, when I run

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM User WHERE ManagerId=xxxxxxxx
```

I get the correct names, still no IDs.

Is this a permission issue? I can't find anything when I login to portal.

I'm running the queries via API on Sandbox environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (both works for me allways):

```java
Id myId = [Select Id From User Where Username = 'myUserName'].Id;
System.debug('#### myId: ' + myId);

List<User> myIdList = [Select Id From User Where Username = 'myUserName' Limit 1];
System.debug('#### myId from list: ' + myIdList[0].Id);
```

Comment: Tried that, still getting Arrays with nulls

Comment: Maybe try to catch the error?
`try{
 Id myId = [Select Id From User Where Username = 'myUserName'].Id;
}
catch(Exception e){
 System.debug('#### error: ' + e.getMesage()); 
}`

Comment: And check your profile, this settings must to be checked: Standard / Custom Object Permissions -> Read, View All

Comment: Another settings for the systemadmin: Author Apex, View All Data, API Enabled

Comment: Thanks for all the answer mast0r. Where can I change Standard / Custom Object Permissions? The User's account which I'm testing is of System Administrator type. So it should have all the permissions granted.

Answer (score 1):

Portal Licence doesn't allow to query User. However you have still access to the name of the user through OwnerId, CreatedById, LastModifiedById using in an inputfield.

i.e :

If you want to have access to user through the portal you need a custom object and synchronise   your records with User by trigger.